# Erro: cannot convert from double to float

Tags: java, ponto-flutuante

Por que `float` não é aceito para os números 0.197 e 0.185?

Código:

```
float salBruto, salLiquido;

Scanner ent = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Informe o seu salário:");
salBruto = ent.nextFloat();

if (salBruto >= 1500 & salBruto <=2500) {
    salLiquido = salBruto + (salBruto * 0.197);
} else {
    if (salBruto > 2500 & salBruto <= 5000) {
        salLiquido = salBruto + (salBruto * 0.185);
    } else {
        if (salBruto < 1500 & salBruto > 5000) {
            salLiquido = salBruto;
        }
    }
}   

ent.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por padrão no java, os números literais com ponto flutuante são considerados pela JVM como do tipo `double`. Você precisa explicitar que aquele número é float, pois o range de valores do tipo double é maior do que o tipo float, e a JVM não faz o cast automático neste caso.

Apenas adicione um `f` ao lado do número literal, pois dessa forma você está informando de forma explicita que aquele valor literal também é um tipo float:

```
float salBruto, salLiquido;

Scanner ent = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Informe o seu salário:");
salBruto = ent.nextFloat();

if (salBruto >= 1500 & salBruto <=2500) {
    salLiquido = salBruto + (salBruto * 0.197f);
} else {
    if (salBruto > 2500 & salBruto <= 5000) {
        salLiquido = salBruto + (salBruto * 0.185f);
    } else {
        if (salBruto < 1500 & salBruto > 5000) {
            salLiquido = salBruto;
        }
    }
}
```